# Feed data to graylog2 from MySql tables

Tags: plugins, elasticsearch, graylog2

I am looking for a way to get a data from few specific MySql tables into graylog2. I have done something similar in ELK using the logstash JDBC input plugin as below,

https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin

Is there a similar way or better way to do it via graylog2

Comment: Did you manage to do that?

Comment: @AlexanderGuz Nope, I didn't I just used logstash. Revisiting my use case the Mysql to ELK was the only thing needed, so felt its better to go for logstash

Answer (score 0):

There is a [plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-gelf.html) to generate messages in GELF format from Logstash, if you want to use Logstash to output events to Graylog2.